# Error with user input for standard deviation program

Tags: python, logic

My program is meant to calculate the standard deviation for 5 values given by the users. There is an issue with my code when getting the input in a for loop. Why is that?

```
givenValues = []

def average(values):
for x in range(0, 6):
    total = total + values[x]
    if(x==5):
        average = total/x
        return average

def sqDiff(values):
    totalSqDiff = 0
    sqDiff = []
    av = average(values)
    for x in range(0,6):
        sqDiff[x] = (values[x] - av)**2
        totalSqDiff = totalSqDiff + sqDiff[x]
    avSqDiff = totalSqDiff / 5
    SqDiffSquared = avSqDiff**2
    return SqDiffSquared

for counter in range(0,6):
    givenValues[counter] = float(input("Please enter a value: "))
counter = counter + 1
sqDiffSq = sqDiff(givenValues)
print("The standard deviation for the given values is: " + sqDiffSq)
```

Comment: post the issue or the error

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.
Which you can easily find out by reading the errormessages your code produces:

1. in the Function average

   insert the line `total = 0`
   you are using it before asigning it.
2. List appending

   Do not use for example
   `sqDiff[x] = (values[x] - av)**2`
   You can do this when using dict's but not lists! Since python cannot be   sure that the list indices will be continuously assigned use `sqDiff.append(...)` instead.
3. Do not concatenate strings with floats. I recommend to read the PEP 0498
   (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which gives you an idea on how string could/should be formated in python